# UserFrom in Excel, VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel with three Sheets, lets call them sheet1, sheet2, sheet3. I have few data points in sheet1, and sheet2 and based on those data points I want to calculate some outcomes in sheet3.

Now I hava created a form in which user could enter the datapoints for sheet1 and sheet2 and on clicking the OK button, sheet3 will be activated and outcomes will be shown.

My questions are:
1. how do i open the userform as soon as the excel file is opened.
2. i dont want to show sheet1 and sheet2 to the user as it also has some propriety datapoints. Given that i have the userform to fill in the required datapoints, how do i hide the actual sheet1 and sheet2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Considering name of the userform to be Userform1, use the below code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```